# Safari Contenteditable responding to focusin at the same time as focusout?

Tags: jquery, safari, contenteditable

I wrote the following code testing with Safari:

```
$(thisinput).children("div").attr ("contenteditable","true") //div editierbar machen
.focus(); //focus setzen
$(thisinput).children("div[contentEditable!=false]").focusout(function(){
$('#log').append("focusout");});
```

My Problem: The event is sent also on "focusin" using SAFARI! Why? Is there a better way?
Thanks 
Michael